# eslint – how to know where a rule is "defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, eslintrc

Given a project with its node's `package.json` installing eslint and a few plugins, how can I know where a particular rule is set?

I see a rule being applied (`space-before-function-paren`) but I cannot find it either in any of the `.eslintrc` files in the project, or in the documentation of the plugins.

Additionally, I'm working with VSCode with some extensions such as ESLint itself, which could potentially be interfering here, but again I'm not sure how/where to check which part is applying that rule (though I think this is unlikely to be happening, as `npm run lint` fails if the code fails against the mentioned rule.

I'm posting the relevant parts of the package.json file:

```js
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "NODE_ENV=development node build/build.js --watch",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=development node build/build.js",
    "build:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node build/build.js",
    "unit": "NODE_ENV=test jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "test": "npm run unit",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs",
    "ci-lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs --format checkstyle --output-file lint_out/unit_timeline.xml"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "autoprefixer": "^8.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "chalk": "^2.3.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^5.10.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "jest-junit": "^3.6.0",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^1.0.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.2.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^2.0.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "postcss-url": "^7.3.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "semver": "^5.5.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.4",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-jest": "^2.3.0",
    "vue-loader": "^14.2.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-file-list-plugin": "0.0.6",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2",
    "yargs": "^11.0.0"
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not extending a configuration that has that rule?

Comment: Do you refer to any `.eslintrc` file that could reside in the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems there's no "eslint" way to perform such a report.

If you run `eslint` with debug options, you get a lot of information about how the program runs: what file is processing, with which configuration, how it fails, etc., but not *from where* a rule was taken.

I managed to find it by simply running a `grep + find` within the `node_modules` directory, and being sure which module was providing the rule by simply changing it and seeing the `eslint` results afterwards.

Comment: It's a shame that they did not give us a way to do this